# Install jenkins 2.50 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, jenkins

Our production CI system is an Ubuntu 14.04 box running Jenkins 2.50.

We want to reproduce that setup on a different box, so that we will be able to test and prepare for some necessary changes without affecting the existing one.

However apt says that version 2.50 doesn't exist (although it clearly [does](https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/)):

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~# apt-get install jenkins=2.50
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.50' for 'jenkins' was not found
```

`apt-cache policy jenkins` shows only version 2.62 as candidate, which in turn requires java8 to be installed (since [2.54](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/04/10/jenkins-has-upgraded-to-java-8/)):

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~# apt-cache policy jenkins
jenkins:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.62
  Version table:
     2.62 0
    500 http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/ binary/ Packages
```

I think I must be missing something very basic, but I cannot understand:

1. Why do I only get the latest version as a candidate?
2. How can I make apt see the older versions?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the Jenkins repository to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and run the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt install jenkins` apt will install the latest version of Jenkins.

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then add the following entry in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian binary/
```

Update your list of available software, then install Jenkins:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install jenkins
```

If you need the *.deb file for a specific version of Jenkins, go to the [Jenkins Debian packages](https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/) webpage, download the Jenkins .deb file manually, and double-click the Jenkins .deb file that you downloaded to open it for installation in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Alternatively you can install jenkins_2.50_all.deb from the terminal by changing directories with `cd` to the directory containing jenkins_2.50_all.deb and installing it using this command:

```
sudo apt install ./jenkins_2.50_all.deb
```

Comment: Hi karel, thanks for the answer. So there is no way that I can make `apt-get install jenkins=2.50` work? I obviously have the jenkins repo in my sources, but I cannot understand why it will only see the latest version as candidate. Is this configurable on the server side?

Comment: apt has 2 features called `apt-mark hold` and `apt-mark unhold` **hold** is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed. **unhold** is used to cancel a previously set hold on a package to allow all actions again. **showhold** is used to print a list of packages on hold in the same way as for the other show commands.