# Trying to install Jenkins on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, jenkins

@Kulfy As advised tried installing the key in source list, got following error:

```
~$ wget -q -o pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
wget: pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key: No such file or directory
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
```

I'm trying to install jenkins on Ubuntu 18.04.
On running the command: `sudo apt install -y jenkins` I'm getting the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package jenkins is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'jenkins' has no installation candidate
```

What needs to be done to proceed with installation of Jenkins?

Comment: You need to add jenkins repository before installation. Try running `wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add - ; echo "deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list` and then `sudo apt update; sudo apt install jenkins`.

Comment: Its also available as a snap in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: @Kulfy: Tried adding jenkins repository as advised, getting following error:

Comment: @Kulfy - The error:                                                                        
 ubuntu@paymechs:~$ wget -q -o https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -;
wget: https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key: No such file or directory
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Comment: @paymechs Please [edit] your question and add the error occurred since formatting in comments make error messages and commands difficult to understand.

Comment: @Kulfy's answer uses `-O` - capital letter O.

Answer (score 1):

I faced pretty much the same issue, till I followed the instructions on the [Jenkins Installation Official Page](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/).

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > \
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is available as a snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install jenkins --classic
```

---

Alternatively go to [Jenkins Debian packages](http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/) website and download the jenkins .deb package. Open the terminal and change directories with `cd` to the directory than contains the jenkins .deb file that you downloaded. Then install jenkins with a command of the form.

```
sudo apt install ./jenkins_2.22X_all.deb
```

where you replace `X` by the last number of the jenkins version that you downloaded.

Alternatively you can add the Jenkins Debian packages repository to your `/etc/apt/source.list` and install it with `sudo apt install jenkins` by following the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/919728).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jenkins&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), there's no package `jenkins` in the official repositories of Ubuntu. If you want to install Jenkins using APT, you need to add Jenkins' official repository and key first. To do that, run:

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add - 
echo "deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install jenkins
```

Reference: [Debian Repository for Jenkins](https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/)